# Processing URLs from list of IDs

Tags: php, macos, curl

I am looking to visit a quantity of URL addresses with one part of the URL being fixed, and other part of the URL being variable. To be more specific, the variable is always a query string.

An example of the URL format is below. The reason for this is because the destination URL is a script which performs a task, based on the integer - but I have a large number of 'id' values to get through. I have the 'id' values ready in a text file, with one value below another (so, separate lines).

> http://www.example.com/thread.php?id=

Previous to my posting here I have experimented with both command line, Apple Script and curl.

My curl script is below.

```
<?php

$lines = file('input/threads.txt');

foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.example.com/thread.php?id=' . $line . '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    }
?>
```

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this task. I am particularly thinking about knowing the status ('how far down the list...') of the task.

Thanks,

Comment: You can use fopen or readfile, as you can see in http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?8,455161

Comment: I think you need some AJAX to do this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the iteration index as a process indicator:

```
$lines = file('input/threads.txt');
$lineCount = count($lines);

foreach ($lines as $index => $line) {
    echo 'fetching URL #' . ($index + 1) . ' of ' . $lineCount . "...\n";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/thread.php?id=' . urlencode($line));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```